# androidのフォアグラウンドサービス化

Tags: android

フォアグラウンドサービス化ですが、開始時5秒以内にstartForegroundを呼び出してユーザーに通知しなければならないと思うのですが、逆に言えば5秒間ならユーザー通知せずフォアグラウンドサービスを使用できるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

はじめまして。
startForegroundServiceで起動したサービスはご説明のとおりstartForegroundを呼び出して通知を伴ったフォアグラウンドサービスにする必要があります。startForegroundはサービス起動後、5秒以内に呼び出さないとANR(=アプリケーション停止)します。
これを呼び出さないでも5秒間サービスは起動できるかというというご質問だと思います。
startForegroundを呼び出さない場合、そのサービスが終了していても、アプリケーションはANR(=アプリケーション応答無し)の状態となります。なので現実的にはこれを利用することはできないと思われます。